# How to convert the string to JSON object using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, string

My string is,

```
var str =
"tmp_IMG-20160309-WA0008-130273657.jpg,tmp_IMG-20160310-WA00002073543746.jpg,tmp_IMG-20160309-WA000792314756.jpg,tmp_IMG-20160310-WA0002-434051888.jpg";
```

I need to convert the above string to JSON Object like

```
[object,object,object]
```

each object have image name.

Comments highly appreciated.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use [`String#split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for building an array with objects

```js
var str = "tmp_IMG-20160309-WA0008-130273657.jpg,tmp_IMG-20160310-WA00002073543746.jpg,tmp_IMG-20160309-WA000792314756.jpg,tmp_IMG-20160310-WA0002-434051888.jpg",
    array = str.split(',').map(function (a) {
        return { src: a };
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "tmp_IMG-20160309-WA0008-130273657.jpg,tmp_IMG-20160310-WA00002073543746.jpg,tmp_IMG-20160309-WA000792314756.jpg,tmp_IMG-20160310-WA0002-434051888.jpg";

var arr = str.split(',').map(e => ({ name: e }));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
var object = JSON.parse(string)
```